Restrictions on a set to be the spectrum of a 1D (discrete) Schrödinger operator.
What restrictions are there on a compact set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ for $E$ to be the spectrum of a bounded (discrete) Schrödinger operator on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$? Is there a known necessary and sufficient condition? How does this change for higher dimensions (i.e., on $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$)?
